# How to expand an 2D array vertically

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been given the task of expanding an array vertical by a certain amount. For example say I have an array like this:

```
[0,0,0,0]
[0,1,1,0]
[0,1,1,0]
[0,0,0,0]
```

and I want to expand it vertically by an amount of 2 resulting in this:

```
[0,0,0,0]
[1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1]
[0,0,0,0]
```

How would I approach this?

Comment: Please provide some code that shows that you have put forth some effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Your conversion from one array to other is not clear

Comment: I don't get the whole conversion process and its rules. But you can simply set the `4` elements (at least for that specific example): `data[1][0] = 1; data[2][0] = 1; data[0][3] = 1; data[2][3] = 1;`. If that does not solve your issue please clarify why.